# MATLAB linking static library?

Tags: matlab, static-libraries, mex

I want to load static library into MATLAB. It is impossible to do with `loadlibrary` function, so I wrote mexfunction where I have placed entry point for the function from my static library. Then I want to create mex file with:

```
mex -v  -Iinclude -Iusr/include mex_func.c libmy_lib.a
```

Header files are stored in include folder (inside current working directory) and header files from some standard libraries used by my `libmy_lib.a` (like FFTW) are stored in `usr/include` folder. As a result, I get error:

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

where all erros are induced by undefined reference to FFTW functions. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Matlab documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#btx0rai-1) you will have to prefix the library with a `-l`, you do not specifiy the extension and you also drop the first `lib`. If the library is not on the system search path, you can also specify a library search path with the `-L` option, before specifying the library. Also, the file to be compiled usually goes last in the mex statement.

```
mex -v  -Iinclude -Iusr/include -Lusr/path_to_my_libfile -lmy_lib  mex_func.c
```

I am not sure if this already solves your problem, but it might help.

Comment: Hi. I have checked that. It gives the same error. So the error is: "All functions within FFTW library have undefined references".Is it possible to link static library in MATLAB if library is created in C with using different static libraries.